# How can we add functional coverage while running simulation using NCSIM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, cadence

I am trying to run a coverage regression using the NC tool from Cadence. I can see RTL coverage, but functional coverage in the scoreboard is missing. How can I add this scoreboard to the `covdut` option in NCSIM arguments?  The scoreboard contains covergroups.

Comment: Is this a UVM scoreboard?

Comment: Yes, it is UVM scoreboard.

Comment: I am viewing it using IMC. And nope, there are no warning messages whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Incisive does not collect functional coverage.  You need to enable it with the **compile-time** `-covfile` option, specifying `select_functional`.

Also, in the source code, you must explicitly call the `sample` function on all covergroups (this applies to all simulators).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was already using these coverpoints in VCS simulations without any issues, so the triggering of coverpoints is ok. Here is what I did to get it working in NC:
1) Add select_functional in the ccf covfile
2) Add option.per_instance=1; in the covergroup declaration

Comment: You can also say irun -coverage a ... so that you don't use any extra file and have everything in one place in your compile script.